# Given two dependent time series, solve for lag using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to estimate the gap (in days) between the two vaccine doses given the time series of number of first doses and second dose. So, the number of 2nd doses at t+n days should be close to the lag(number of 1st doses at day t, n days). As a starting point, I picked (based on some information) n = 49 days until May 16th, 2021 and and 84 days thereafter. Now, when I am plotting the known number of second_dose_administered and the est_second_dose, I ofcourse am seeing they are close, but not much.

Is there a way to figure out n in the equation est_second_dose = lag(first_dose_administered, n) so that the difference between second_dose_administered (known) and est_second_dose (estimated) is minimum?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)

vacc <- read_csv("https://api.covid19india.org/csv/latest/tested_numbers_icmr_data.csv")

vacc_df <- vacc %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(str_sub(update_time_stamp, 1, 10))) %>% 
  filter(date > "2021-01-16") %>% 
  select(date, first_dose_administered, second_dose_administered) %>% 
  relocate(date) %>% 
  mutate(est_second_dose = if_else(date < "2021-05-16", 
                                   lag(first_dose_administered, 49), 
                                   lag(first_dose_administered, 84)))

vacc_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brute force method that should be fine in this case, since the # of days is a small number. In this case we can afford to do an inefficient crossing of the data with itself and then filter for the first second dose date that exceeds the number of doses for each first dose date.

It might better to use `approx()` to interpolate values for a more precise fit, or to use `data.table` or `sqldf` to perform the "non-equi join" that I'm doing inefficiently here. But at this scale my quick and dirty approach works well enough and calculates pretty much instantly.

```
vacc %>% 
   clean_names() %>% 
   mutate(date = dmy(str_sub(update_time_stamp, 1, 10))) %>% 
   filter(date > "2021-01-16") %>% 
   select(date, first_dose_administered, second_dose_administered) %>%
   pivot_longer(-date) %>% mutate(dummy = 1) -> vacc_long


left_join(vacc_long %>% filter(name %>% str_starts("first")),
          vacc_long %>% filter(name %>% str_starts("second")), by = "dummy") %>%
   filter(value.y >= value.x) %>%
   group_by(date.x) %>%
   slice_min(date.y) %>%
   mutate(lag = date.y - date.x) %>%
   ggplot(aes(date.x, lag)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, Jon! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to make sure the 2nd dose dates (date.y) are unique and sequential with exactly 1 day gap?

Comment: You could use `base::seq.Date` or the `padr` package to help with that.